# Apple Mail - extra notification on specific mailbox

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app, gmail, notifications

I'm using Apple Mail on my MAC, switched notifications on (working). Connected account is hosted by Google so I'm using labels feature very offten (Mailbox in Apple Mail). However, if I move incomming message into specific label (without getting into Inbox), I'm receiving no notification.

Point is that as developer, I'm using extra label (mailbox) for server errors and would be really fine to have any notification on it, or better, special (more annoying) one.

Any clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you :)
In Mail Preferences, General settings ....
New message Notification...All mail boxes :) or pick one !

[image]

Comment: My man, thank you! I was blind or don't know that I have missed that configuration settings. Maybe confused that it's not directly under it :-D Seems there is no possibility to setup another sound/notification policy without extra SW, so thanks for that, definitelly.

Comment: You are welcome. If you still want some kind of nuclear explosion warning (more annoying) that a message has arrived from a specific account, lets post it as separate question. Since it could be done in different way and possibly with Automator.